# Selection of specific element in a cell in python

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, indexing

I have a list made of several matrices. In my case i have a list of 12 matrices.
I would like to create a for loop able to select specific matrices and append them.
As example, from the list extract the matrices at index 0, 4 and 8 and add together in order to create a new bigger matrix, so extract the matrices in the previous list at index 1,5,9 and add together, so extract the matrices in the list at index 2,6 and 10 and than the matrices on the list at index 3, 7 and 11. Now i have 12 matrix but in general i can have a list - cell - of n matrix. I would like also to put all those bigger matrices, now i have 4 matrices, in a new list or cell.

I prepared this for loop but the result is not what i'm expecting:

```
num_of_class = 4
len_cell_matrix = len(cell_matrix)
New_cell = ([])

for i in range(0,len_cell_matrix):
    matrix_select = cell_matrix[i:i+num_of_class-1,len_cell_matrix-num_of_class]
    new_cell.append(matrix_select)
```

the cell, cell_matrix, in my example contains 12 matrices. How to generalize for n matrices?

Thank's

Comment: *"add together in order to create a new bigger matrix"* This is not a well defined operation. Do you want to concatenate them vertically (more rows), horizontally (more columns), or pair-wise add their cell-values (which doesn't create a bigger matrix but one with bigger values)?

Comment: more than concatenate the matrices, i would like to rearrange the order of the matrices inside the original cell and create a new cell. If now the order of the matrices in the original list is: old_cell([m0], [m1],[m2]......[m12]), the new cell have to be like new_celll = ([m0],m[4],[m8],[m1],[m5],[m9],[m2],[m6],[m10]....)

Comment: can you add a detailed example of what you expect your output to be? Like at each step, what should exactly happen, with example. Considering taking a long list of matrices and add a step by step explanation.

Comment: let's to have a starting cell made of 6 matrices, but in general i can have any number of matrices inside the cell. Old_cell = ([matrix0],[matrix1],[matrix2],[martrix3,],[matrix4],[matrix5],[matrix6]). I want to  rearrange the position of the matrix automatically knowing that every 3 step i have similar matrix. So the new cell will be: new_cell = ([matrix0],[matrix2],[matrix5],[matrix1],[matrix3],[matrix6]). I could have also 12 matrices in the starting cell and the step could be 4. hope i described better my problem